# What control should i use to display dynamic data (pictures, names etc) like an html table on asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, datatable

The source of my problem is my lack of experience with asp.net. I'm trying to display my videos in database as a html like table. Much like the main page of youtube or other video sharing websites.

To give more detail, I need to display small pictures that are linked to watch.aspx that are concerned of duration, name, users, and the thumbnail of the video.

Right now I'm creating a dynamic html table on the codebehind (programmatically creating href, div, img etc.. tags), resulting unnecessary more coding, a hard way to edit the design, less flexibility.

I know there are some nice controls that are being used in asp.net like gridview etc.. But I'm not experienced to select which or how to use.

Am I doing it the right way, or should I make them user controls, or use something like gridview, datalist, datatable?

More spesific, what is the best way to create the main page or search page of youtube on asp.net?

to give you a hint; this is what I'm asking about:
[image: what is the best way to create this table?]

Comment: If you can afford the licensing, you should look at [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) if the standard .Net controls aren't fancy enough for you.

Comment: The image you uploaded is too small to see anything in detail, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx) - ASP.NET Server control and set `RepeatColumns=n` property to display `n` columns per row.

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress controls are also very good .... here is the link to their asp.net controls http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/